# How to set the Origin (drag.origin) for drag behavior in d3 JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag

I am trying to implement drag behavior for group consisting from HTML-text and background-rectangle using the d3 framework. I was able to get it working, although when not setting the drag.origin I can see noticeable jump due to the mouse-position/element-coordinates offset. Exactly how described on the [d3 wiki-page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior)
Although the page described how to set the Origin for dragging, I do not properly understand how ti implement it in my example. I tried two different approaches : using the  element for grouping the elements together and defining new  element holding tose. In the first case I have to use the translate-function and I do not even know how to get the coordinates of the group.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500);

var group = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)")
  .attr("id", "group");

var rect1 = group.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("rx", 6)
  .attr("ry", 6)
  .attr("x", 5/2)
  .attr("y", 5/2)
  .attr("id", "rect")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 125)
  .style("fill", 'white')
  .style("stroke", d3.scale.category20c())
  .style('stroke-width', 5);


var html1 = group.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("id", "fobject")
  .style("border-color", d3.scale.category20c())
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
  .html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam.");

var innerSvg = svg.append("svg")
  .attr("x", 500)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("id", "innerSvg");

var rect2 = innerSvg.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("rx", 6)
  .attr("ry", 6)
  .attr("x", 5/2)
  .attr("y", 5/2)
  .attr("id", "rect")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 125)
  .style("fill", 'white')
  .style("stroke", d3.scale.category20c())
  .style('stroke-width', 5);

var html2 = innerSvg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("id", "fobject")
  .style("border-color", d3.scale.category20c())
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
  .html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam.");

var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
            return "translate(" + [ d3.event.x,d3.event.y ] + ")"
        })
    });

var drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("x", d3.event.x)
        .attr("y", d3.event.y);
    });

group.call(drag1);
innerSvg.call(drag2);
```

I would very appreciate any explanation, naturally I prepared a working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Y8y7V/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You simply need to set the `origin()` function accordingly. In the second case this is straightforward, in the first case somewhat more difficult because you are using coordinates as well as a transform. The basic pattern (for the second case) looks like this:

```
 .origin(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8y7V/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. In the first case I can simply add the x/y coordinates as parameter of the <g> element. I wonder how can I set the translation parameter according to the defined x/y parameters, like : var group = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + [ this.attr("x"),this.attr("y") ] + ")")
This of ocourse wont work, because this references the window object.

Comment: If you set the `origin()` appropriately, you don't need to set the transform based on the static coordinates.

Comment: Which does not solve my problem - question for which I was not able to find answer yet - how to GET the position of the group, the <g>-element, when I can only use the "transformation" to set its position.
Thanks anyhow, your previous explanation solved my problem and i was able to find a working solution for booth cases.

Answer (score 0):

group element has no x/y attributes - no problem! create ones:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr('x',x_1)
            .attr('y',y_1)
            .attr("class","node")
            .attr("name","Node_A")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + x_1 + ", " + y_1 +")")
            .call(drag);
```

when, the .origin function from Lars will work

and dont forget to update x,y attributes, while dragging:

```
function dragged() {

    d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.x + ", " + d3.event.y +")");
    d3.select(this).attr("x",d3.event.x);
    d3.select(this).attr("y",d3.event.y);
}
```