# Why are d, this, and the variable all undefined in my drag function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to do some logic based on the coordinates of a rectangle, when dragged. I want to select all circles within the rectangle.

```
function dragmove(d) {
    var barz = document.querySelector("#visual");

    var point = d3.mouse(barz),
        tempP = {
            x: point[0],
            y: point[1]
        };

        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

        d3.select(this).style({
            opacity: 0.05
        })
        console.log(selectionBox.x); //turns out undefined
        console.log(d.x); //also undefined
        console.log(d3.select(this)); //undefined

        vis.selectAll("circle").filter(function (d, i) {
            return (d.x > d3.select(this).x && d.x < (d3.select(this).x + d3.select(this).width))
        }).style({
            opacity: 0.1
        });
```

If you didn't already notice, right now I only have it checking within the x coordinates, at least until I finish fixing this. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/rm48pcwL/)

Whenever I try to run it, it doesn't pull any errors, but it doesn't work as intended because the reference is undefined. Is there any reason why none of the references work at all?

To reproduce this you need to first drag on the canvas to draw a rectangle, and then drag that rectangle

Comment: I don’t get any `undefined` in my console. What are the conditions to reproduce this?

Comment: Also, why is there JavaScript code inside a `<script>` tag with an `src` attribute?!

Comment: Which of those references are defined depends on what you have clicked on and dragged.

Comment: @Xufox Oh I'm so sorry. To reproduce this you need to first drag on the canvas to draw a rectangle, and then drag that rectangle

Comment: @Xufox the code within the src is for enabling mathJax bits but that's not really related, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @SMcCrohan I updated to represent what should be done to recreate but the idea is that all of them represent the same one rectangle.

Comment: I added `console.log(d)` to the drag handler and d is *always* undefined, even when you're initially selecting a rectangle.

Comment: @James yeah, that's what I'm struggling with right now. For some reason the entire rectangle object becomes undefined before dragging

Comment: To me that means the function doesn't receive a parameter.  Can you get the values expected in d from the event perhaps?

Comment: @James well, I cut it down in the code block above, but all drag functions, including the canvas drag, use this one function, so the parameters are in order.    Is that what you mean?

Comment: @James I inserted a console.log(this) at the start of the drag, and it's still defined at that point

Comment: For some reason `d3.select(this)` is undefined even though `this` is defined, but I can't work with just `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your origin function isn't quite right.  I tried the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966503/535480)

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) {
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")}; 
    })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarter)
    .on("drag", dragmove);
```

Now it passes in a valid object to the dragmove function.

In the following code:

```
vis.selectAll("circle").filter(function (d, i) {
    return (d.x > d3.select(this).x && d.x < (d3.select(this).x + d3.select(this).width))
})...
```

the reference to `this` is undefined because of how the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function works.  According to the specs, we can provide our own `this` as the second parameter to the filter function, so:

```
vis.selectAll("circle").filter(function (d, i) {
    return (d.x > d3.select(this).x && d.x < (d3.select(this).x + d3.select(this).width))
}, this)...
```

[Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rm48pcwL/3/)

Comment: Hold on a sec, dragmove has a parameter, `d`, seen in  `function dragmove(d) {code}`.

Also, d3.select(this) is still undefined, inside or outside of the filter function.

Comment: You're right, the origin function wasn't returning the proper object, and it was passing undefined to the dragmove function.

Comment: Yeah, but `d3.select(this).x` is still undefined for me in your fiddle. Is there anything else that is wrong?

Comment: d3.select(whatever) returns a collection of stuff, so you have to use .attr("x") instead of .x

Comment: one last question, but I'm trying to use `d3.select(this).attr("initx")` to get the value of `initx`, a property of the circle that is defined with `x`, but for some reason, it keeps popping up as undefined, [as can be seen from the console from here](http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/rm48pcwL/5/). Is there any reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: A new question doesn't belong in the comments.  Your makedots function sets nodes to an array of objects with initx properties.  Are you sure that setting .data(nodes) creates those attributes in the svg elements?  I would assume not.  You already have some other attributes you are adding with .attr, I would think you should do that.  Please ask a new question for any follow-up.

Comment: ok, thanks, and one last question that is actually relevant to this one, but is there any way to set the origin for each object to the pixel coordinates of (0,0) for the graph? Using this origin function is actually messing my program up, because the (0,0) coordinate for each point shifts whenever a drag first occurs

Comment: [Here's a link to a new question about the one that I just asked you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586479/how-do-i-set-the-origin-for-my-objects-to-the-svgs-0-0-in-d3)